# Button not working after javascript call

Tags: jsf, primefaces

By clicking a commandLink, I call an event on actionListener and after that, my dataGrid updates via AJAX then, onComplete, I call a javascript. It works fine on the first time but when I click the commandLink again, it does nothing.

Here's my code:

```
<p:commandLink id="addCompBtn" value="Add Computer" actionListener="#{coltsysLab.addComputer}" update=":organizeForm:availableComputers :organizeForm:labStat" oncomplete="getPos();"/>
```

My Javascript just positions each computer in a specific fixed location.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what getPos() does; however, let's assume that it does not release event binding to the input DOM.

Try updating the commandLink as well:

```
<p:commandLink id="addCompBtn" value="Add Computer" actionListener="#{coltsysLab.addComputer}" update="@this,availableComputers,labStat" oncomplete="getPos();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing `oncomplete="getPos();"` from your button and test again. If the button works fine beyond the 1st time then the problem must come from your JavaScript function. If that's the case, you should use the Developer Tools on any browser to investigate the issue. For example, on Chrome browser, right-click anywhere on the page then click `Inspect Element`, the `Console` section might help.